# VBnet Accessing individual bits of a byte // BitArray length & count are equal to the byte value?

Tags: vb.net, byte, bitarray

I'm trying to communicate with a PLC that accepts/sends 16-bit values, with each single bit allowing for a check to happen or not.

To do this, I've been attempting to use the .Net BitArray but the results have been anything but succesful.

The underlaying structure is made out of an array of two bytes, both bytes are initialised with the value 0.

When I create a new bitarray using one of these bytes, I expected to get an array with 8 values set to false. **This is not the case**.

With a byte value of 0, the length and count of the bitarray is also zero. While I could presume that leading zeros are dropped, this seems very counterintuitive.

When I create a bitarray using a byte with the value of 200, I expected to get an array with 8 values (*True, True, False, False, True, False, False, False*). However, I instead get a bitarray with a length and count of **200**?

Code is currently this :

```
Private FaultBits as Byte = 0
Public Sub SetBitValue(index As Integer, value As Boolean)
    Try
        If index < 0 Then
            Throw New Exception("Index is below zero!")
        End If

        If index > 7 Then
            Throw New Exception("Index out of bounds! Maximum allowed index value is 7")
        End If

        'If BitConverter.IsLittleEndian Then
            'ToDo
        'End If

        Dim bitArray_Section As BitArray = Nothing
        
            bitArray_Section = New BitArray(FaultBits)
            'bitArray_Section.Length = 8  'Truncates incorrectly
            bitArray_Section.Item(index) = value 'Set the individual bit
            FaultBits = ConvertToByte(bitArray_Section) 'Set back to byte


    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("clsFaultBits : SetBitValue : w. Index " & index & " : Exception : " & ex.Message())
    End Try
End Sub
```

And the get-equivalent :

```
 Public Function GetBitValue(index As Integer) As Boolean
    Try
        If index < 0 Then
            Throw New Exception("Index is below zero!")
        End If

        If index > 7 Then
            Throw New Exception("Index out of bounds! Maximum allowed index value is 7")
        End If


        Dim bitArray_Section As BitArray = Nothing
        
            bitArray_Section = New BitArray(FaultBits)
            'bitArray_Section.Length = 8
            Return bitArray_Section.Item(index)
        
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("clsFaultBits : GetBitValue : w. Index " & index & " : Exception : " & ex.Message())
    End Try
End Function
```

The convert function, I assumed this would have a length of 8 which is wrong :

```
Public Function ConvertToByte(bits As BitArray) As Byte
    Try
        If bits.Count <> 8 Then
            Throw New Exception("Invalid amount of bits!")
        End If

        Dim returnbyte(1) As Byte
        bits.CopyTo(returnbyte, 0)
        Return returnbyte(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("clsFaultBits : ConvertToByte : Exception : " & ex.Message())
    End Try
End Function
```

> ByteValue :: BitarrayLength / Count

> 0 :: 0 / 0

> 200 :: 200 / 200

> 10 :: 10 / 10

What I would like to accomplish :

> Receive a byte (1-0-0-1-0-0-1-0)
>
> Enable the booleans in the program by reading the individual bits:
> Check1, Check4, Check7
>
> Set the individual bits of the output Byte starting at 0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0
>
> Turn on 5 : 0-0-0-0-1-0-0-0
>
> Turn on 2 : 0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0
>
> Send Byte

Am I completely misusing the BitArray class? What am I doing wrong?
What would allow me to change individual bit values without running into this chaos?

Why is the length / count of the BitArray the same value as the Byte, instead of the amount of bits the Byte is composed of?

I am aware the code has yet to take in account endian-ness.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What data type does the API of the PLC accept? Can you link to an online documentation?

Comment: @djv The PLC accepts Bytes sent via TCP/IP, it is not attached directly to the system so I don't know the exact type, I can communicate with it and receive/send bytes succesfully.  The issue is more than I can't split the bytes into sets of 8 booleans that I require to know what it is trying to tell me.

The BitArray class looks like what I need, but it doesn't seem to function in that regard.

Comment: Well to check if a certain bit is set in a number, you can do this: `Dim nThBitSet As Boolean = (number And n) = n`

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure BitArray class is what you need. Anyway you can't create a BitArray from an Integer value. The statement `New BitArray(200)`, for example, will create a BitArray of 200 items all set to 0. 
If you need to send 16-bit values I think it would be simpler to use `UShort` (also called `UInt16`) datatype instead of a BitArray and use @djv suggestion to check the single bit. To set bits you have to make use of some "binary" algebra and the `And` operator. Remember to always use unsigned datatypes and be aware that bit count starts from right.

Comment: The odd thing is, I'm not creating it from an integer value, I'm passing a byte to the constructor? Is it interpreting the byte itself as the definition of the array size?

Comment: It was exactly that, it implicitly used the value of the byte as an integer to define the length of the BitArray. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately BitArray does not allow you to convert to/from a 16 bit value.

However, it does work for Byte() and Integer().

So we can convert from/to a 32 bit integer and that should work just fine.

It also not clear how you have your original data. As two separate bytes, or as a single 16 bit value?

I will assume a single unsinged 16 bit value.

So we will have this code:

```
Sub Testset()

    Dim i16 As UInt16
    i16 = 255
    SetBits(i16, 9, False)
    SetBits(i16, 9, True)

    Debug.Print(GetBits(i16, 9).ToString)

End Sub
```

Output from above:

```
00000000 11111111
00000010 11111111
True
```

And the two routines are:

```
Public Sub SetBits(ByRef My16Bits As UInt16, MyINdex As Integer, MyValue As Boolean)

    ' toss the passed 16 bits into a 32 bit interger 
    ' we do this, since the conversion routines only work
    ' for built in primitaves ike byte() or integer(). 

    Dim My32(0) As Integer
    My32(0) = My16Bits

    Dim My32Bits As New BitArray(New Integer() {My32(0)})

    My32Bits(MyINdex) = MyValue

    ' now convert bit array back to our 32 bit integer
    My32Bits.CopyTo(My32, 0)

    ' now copy our 32 bit interger back to that 16 bit
    My16Bits = My32(0)

    For i = 15 To 0 Step -1
        Debug.Write(IIf(My32Bits(i), "1", "0"))
        If i = 8 Then Debug.Write(" ")
    Next i
    Debug.Print("")

End Sub

Public Function GetBits(My16Bits As UInt16, MyIndex As Integer) As Boolean

    ' convert Int16 to bit array
    Dim My32(0) As Integer
    My32(0) = My16Bits
    Dim My32Bits As New BitArray(New Integer() {My32(0)})

    Return My32Bits(MyIndex)

End Function
```

Of course one would remove that loop that displays the values.

And if this had to be called a "lot" of times before you want the bit array converted one way or the other - then you might separate out the converting to a bit array as a separate routine, and the pass that to the get/set bit routines and then do a final call of code to convert the bitArrary back to the Int16 value. It really depends on how many times you expect to get/set bits. So 1 or 2 times, then above is fine. If  you have to always test many bits and set many bits, then convert the value to a bit array before you call + use the two routines to set/get the value. So the code that converts to and from the bit array could be separated out as separate code.

Comment: The data is obtained in a byte() array, though I've been looking into handling one set of 8 bits at a time since the original PLC message is in the first byte, the outgoing communication is in the second byte. I need to be able to set individual bits in both parts of the byte array.

What I don't understand is : 

Dim myByteArray() as Byte = {0,200}

Dim bitArray_Section1 as BitArray = New BitArray(myByteArray(0))

Dim bitArray_Section2 as BitArray = New BitArray(myByteArray(1))

Why is the length/count the same as the byte value? Am I not sending a primitive byte to the constructor?

Comment: Solved, the Byte was casted implicitly to an integer to be used as the length of the BitArray, sending in the full array got the behaviour I needed and expected.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs it, I wrote a `BitStream` class.

Use it just like a `FileStream` or `MemoryStream`, but, instead of feeding it bytes, give it bits, which you can do in two ways: `Write` converts each value to a *single* bit (0 = 0, non-zero = 1) and `WriteFrom___` writes the specified number of individual bits from the value supplied, starting with the right-most bit.

Likewise, you can read individual bits one at a time, or specify a number of bits to be returned in a `Byte`, `UShort`, or `UInteger`.

Once populated, use `ToCompactArray` for a byte array that you can store. Later, create a new `BitStream` instance using the compact array.

Have a good read through the code before using, so you see what's possible.

EDIT: Added a constructor that takes the original stream length along with a compact array for when it was not a multiple of 8.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Math

Public Class BitStream


#Region "Consts & Vars"

  Private Const DEF_CAP As Integer = 256
  Private Const ADD_B As Integer = DEF_CAP >> 3
  Private Const MASK As Byte = 255

  Private ext, pos, byt, bit, ub As Integer
  Private B() As Byte

#End Region ' Consts & Vars


#Region "Public Methods - Write"

  ''' <summary>Writes a Bit at the current position then advances to the next position.</summary>
  ''' <param name="value">The value to write. A non-zero value equates to 1.</param>
  Public Sub Write(value As Byte)
    SetBit(value)
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>Writes a Bit at the current position then advances to the next position.</summary>
  ''' <param name="value">The value to write. A non-zero value equates to 1.</param>
  Public Sub Write(value As Integer)
    SetBit(value)
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>Writes a Bit at the current position then advances to the next position.</summary>
  ''' <param name="value">The value to write. False equates to 0 and True equates to 1.</param>
  Public Sub Write(value As Boolean)
    SetBit(value)
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>Writes a series of Bits starting at the current position then advances to the position after.</summary>
  ''' <param name="values">An array of values to write. Non-zero values equate to 1.</param>
  Public Sub Write(values() As Byte)
    For Each v As Byte In values : SetBit(v) : Next
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>Writes a series of Bits starting at the current position then advances to the position after.</summary>
  ''' <param name="values">An array of values to write. Non-zero values equate to 1.</param>
  Public Sub Write(values() As Integer)
    For Each v As Integer In values : SetBit(v) : Next
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>Writes a series of Bits starting at the current position then advances to the position after.</summary>
  ''' <param name="values">An array of values to write. False equates to 0 and True equates to 1.</param>
  Public Sub Write(values() As Boolean)
    For Each v As Boolean In values : SetBit(v) : Next
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>Writes the specified number of bits from the byte into the stream and advances to the position after.</summary>
  ''' <param name="b">The byte whose bits to read.</param>
  ''' <param name="bitcount">A value between 1 and 8.</param>
  Public Sub WriteFromByte(b As Byte, bitcount As Integer)
    If bitcount < 1 OrElse bitcount > 8 Then
      Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Bitcount must be between 1 and 8 inclusive.")
    Else
      For i As Integer = 0 To bitcount - 1
        SetBit(Sign(b And (1 << i)))
      Next
    End If
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>Writes the specified number of bits from the UInt16 into the stream and advances to the position after.</summary>
  ''' <param name="u">The UInt16 whose bits to read.</param>
  ''' <param name="bitcount">A value between 1 and 16.</param>
  Public Sub WriteFromUInt16(u As UInt16, bitcount As Integer)
    If bitcount < 1 OrElse bitcount > 16 Then
      Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Bitcount must be between 1 and 16 inclusive.")
    Else
      For i As Integer = 0 To bitcount - 1
        SetBit(Sign(u And (1 << i)))
      Next
    End If
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>Writes the specified number of bits from the UInt32 into the stream and advances to the position after.</summary>
  ''' <param name="u">The UInt32 whose bits to read.</param>
  ''' <param name="bitcount">A value between 1 and 32.</param>
  Public Sub WriteFromUInt32(u As UInt32, bitcount As Integer)
    If bitcount < 1 OrElse bitcount > 32 Then
      Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Bitcount must be between 1 and 32 inclusive.")
    Else
      For i As Integer = 0 To bitcount - 1
        SetBit(Sign(u And (1 << i)))
      Next
    End If
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>Sets the Bit value at the specified offset without changing Position.</summary>
  ''' <param name="offset">The offset to write to.</param>
  ''' <param name="value">The Bit value to write. Non-zero values equate to 1.</param>
  Public Sub Poke(offset As Integer, value As Integer)
    If offset < 0 OrElse offset > Length Then
      Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Offset must be between 0 and Length inclusive.")
    Else
      If value Then
        B(offset >> 3) = B(offset >> 3) Or (1 << (offset And 7))
      Else
        B(offset >> 3) = B(offset >> 3) And (MASK - (1 << (offset And 7)))
      End If
      If offset = ext + 1 Then ext = offset
    End If
  End Sub

#End Region ' Public Methods - Write


#Region "Public Methods - Read"

  ''' <summary>Reads a Bit from the stream and advances the position within the stream by one Bit, or returns -1 if at the end of the stream.</summary>
  ''' <returns>The Bit cast to an Integer, or -1 if at the end of the stream.</returns>
  Public Function Read() As Integer
    If pos > ext Then
      Return -1
    Else
      Read = Sign(B(byt) And (1 << bit))
      pos += 1
      bit += 1
      If bit = 8 Then
        bit = 0
        byt += 1
        If byt > ub Then
          ub += ADD_B
          ReDim Preserve B(ub)
        End If
      End If
    End If
  End Function

  ''' <summary>Reads the specified number of bits, copies them into a byte, and advances to the position after. An exception is thrown if there are not enough remaining bits in the stream from the current position.</summary>
  ''' <param name="bitcount">A value between 1 and 8 inclusive.</param>
  Public Function ReadToByte(bitcount As Integer) As Byte
    If bitcount < 1 OrElse bitcount > 8 Then
      Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Bitcount must be between 1 and 8 inclusive.")
    Else
      Dim r, i As Integer, b As Byte
      For i = 0 To bitcount - 1
        r = Read()
        If r = -1 Then Throw New EndOfStreamException
        If r Then b = b Or (1 << i)
      Next
      Return b
    End If
  End Function

  ''' <summary>Reads the specified number of bits, copies them into a UInt16, and advances to the position after. An exception is thrown if there are not enough remaining bits in the stream from the current position.</summary>
  ''' <param name="bitcount">A value between 1 and 16 inclusive.</param>
  Public Function ReadToUInt16(bitcount As Integer) As UInt16
    If bitcount < 1 OrElse bitcount > 16 Then
      Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Bitcount must be between 1 and 16 inclusive.")
    Else
      Dim r, i As Integer, u As UInt16
      For i = 0 To bitcount - 1
        r = Read()
        If r = -1 Then Throw New EndOfStreamException
        If r Then u = u Or (1 << i)
      Next
      Return u
    End If
  End Function

  ''' <summary>Reads the specified number of bits, copies them into a UInt32, and advances to the position after. An exception is thrown if there are not enough remaining bits in the stream from the current position.</summary>
  ''' <param name="bitcount">A value between 1 and 32 inclusive.</param>
  Public Function ReadToUInt32(bitcount As Integer) As UInt32
    If bitcount < 1 OrElse bitcount > 32 Then
      Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Bitcount must be between 1 and 32 inclusive.")
    Else
      Dim r, i As Integer, u As UInt32
      For i = 0 To bitcount - 1
        r = Read()
        If r = -1 Then Throw New EndOfStreamException
        If r Then u = u Or (1 << i)
      Next
      Return u
    End If
  End Function

  ''' <summary>Reads the Bit value at the specified offset and returns it cast to an Integer, without changing Position. Returns -1 if offset is at end of stream. Throws an exception if out of range.</summary>
  ''' <param name="offset">The offset to read at.</param>
  Public Function Peek(offset As Integer) As Integer
    If offset < 0 OrElse offset > Length Then
      Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Offset must be between 0 and Length inclusive.")
    ElseIf offset = Length Then
      Return -1
    Else
      Return Sign(B(offset >> 3) And (1 << (offset And 7)))
    End If
  End Function

#End Region ' Public Methods - Read


#Region "Public Methods - Misc"

  ''' <summary>Creates a new BitStream and sets the initial Bit capacity.</summary>
  ''' <param name="capacity">Capacity stated in Bits. If less than 1, the default value will be used.</param>
  Public Sub New(Optional capacity As Integer = DEF_CAP)
    ub = (If(capacity < 1, DEF_CAP, capacity) - 1) >> 3
    ReDim B(ub)
    ext = -1
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>Creates a new BitStream from the CompactArray. Length will be set to 8 * byte count. For precision, when the original stream length was not a multiple of 8, use the overload that takes a 'StreamLen' value.</summary>
  ''' <param name="CompactArray">An array whose bits will be used to populate the stream. The position will remain at the start, ready for reading.</param>
  Public Sub New(CompactArray() As Byte)
    ub = CompactArray.Length - 1
    ReDim B(ub)
    CompactArray.CopyTo(B, 0)
    ext = ((ub + 1) << 3) - 1
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>Creates a new BitStream from the CompactArray and sets the stream length to the specified value. Throws an exception if empty or if StreamLen does not fall within the final byte.</summary>
  ''' <param name="CompactArray">An array whose bits will be used to populate the stream. The position will remain at the start, ready for reading.</param>
  ''' <param name="StreamLen">The length of the stream when the compact array was generated.</param>
  Public Sub New(CompactArray() As Byte, StreamLen As Integer)
    If CompactArray.Length = 0 Then
      Throw New ArgumentException("CompactArray must contain at least one byte.")
    ElseIf StreamLen < (CompactArray.Length << 3) - 7 OrElse StreamLen > (CompactArray.Length << 3) Then
      Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("StreamLen must fall within the final byte.")
    Else
      ub = CompactArray.Length - 1
      ReDim B(ub)
      CompactArray.CopyTo(B, 0)
      ext = StreamLen - 1
    End If
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>Sets the position within the stream to the specified value.</summary>
  ''' <param name="offset">The new position within the stream. This is relative to the orig parameter and can be positive or negative.</param>
  ''' <param name="origin">The seek reference point.</param>
  Public Sub Seek(offset As Integer, Optional origin As SeekOrigin = SeekOrigin.Begin)
    Dim newpos As Integer
    Select Case origin
      Case SeekOrigin.Begin : newpos = offset
      Case SeekOrigin.Current : newpos = pos + offset
      Case SeekOrigin.End : newpos = Length + offset
    End Select
    If newpos < 0 OrElse newpos > Length Then
      Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Seek position must be between 0 and Length inclusive.")
    Else
      If pos <> newpos Then
        pos = newpos
        byt = pos >> 3
        bit = newpos And 7
        If byt > ub Then
          ub += ADD_B
          ReDim Preserve B(ub)
        End If
      End If
    End If
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>Trims the capacity to fit the written Bits.</summary>
  Public Sub Trim()
    Dim n As Integer = Length >> 3
    If ub > n Then
      ub = n
      ReDim Preserve B(ub)
    End If
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>Returns a byte array with every 8 bits from the stream occupying one byte.</summary>
  Public Function ToCompactArray() As Byte()
    Dim n As Integer = Length >> 3
    Dim a(n) As Byte
    For i As Integer = 0 To n
      a(i) = B(i)
    Next
    Return a
  End Function

  ''' <summary>Returns a tuple containing a byte array (with each set of 8 bits from the stream occupying one byte) and the stream length.</summary>
  Public Function ToCompactArrayWithLength() As (Byte(), Integer)
    Return (ToCompactArray, Length)
  End Function

#End Region ' Public Methods - Misc


#Region "Properties"

  ''' <summary>Gets the current position within the stream.</summary>
  Public ReadOnly Property Position As Integer
    Get
      Return pos
    End Get
  End Property

  ''' <summary>Gets the length of the stream in bits.</summary>
  Public ReadOnly Property Length As Integer
    Get
      Return ext + 1
    End Get
  End Property

  ''' <summary>Returns the current capacity of the stream. Call Trim to fit to the written data.</summary>
  Public ReadOnly Property Capacity As Integer
    Get
      Return (ub + 1) << 3
    End Get
  End Property

#End Region ' Properties


#Region "Private Subs"

  Private Sub SetBit(bitval As Integer)
    If bitval Then
      B(byt) = B(byt) Or (1 << bit)
    Else
      B(byt) = B(byt) And (MASK - (1 << bit))
    End If
    If pos = ext + 1 Then ext = pos
    pos += 1
    bit += 1
    If bit = 8 Then
      bit = 0
      byt += 1
      If byt > ub Then
        ub += ADD_B
        ReDim Preserve B(ub)
      End If
    End If
  End Sub

#End Region ' Private Subs


End Class
```